# How to change browsermob-proxy logging when using the Embedded Mode with Maven?

Tags: logging, browsermob

I have browsermob-proxy included in my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

I saw on the browsermob-proxy site a section talking about how to change the Logging (https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy):

> When running in stand-alone mode, the proxy loads the default logging configuration from the conf/bmp-logging.properties file. To increase/decrease the logging level, change the logging entry for net.lightbody.bmp.

So then I see in the github (https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/blob/master/browsermob-dist/src/main/config/bmp-logging.properties) a properties file that I can alter to get the logging I need, but I am not sure how to alter this file, or where to find it since I used it as a Maven Dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BrowserMob Proxy uses slf4j for logging, so when you're running in embedded mode, BMP will use whatever logging framework your application uses (log4j, logback, java util logging, etc.). You do need to provide an slf4j binding for your logging framework -- see the [SLF4J FAQ](http://slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping) and Manual for more info.

After your application's logging framework is set up, you can configure BMP logging the same way you configure any other logger throughout your application. BMP follows the standard Java practice of using the fully-qualified class name as the logger name.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I suppose I haven't messed with logging at all and so am still a bit lost. I will utilize the FAQ you linked and hopefully gain a better understanding.